# Apache Archiva throws DavException: (400) Bad Request when called in browser to http://archiva/repository/releases/

Tags: java, maven, archiva

I use Apache Archiva 2.2.10 on Rhel8 server. This is the *.war* running in Tomcat **9.0.65**. When I do a call to *http://archiva/repository/releases/* Archiva throws DavException: (400) Bad Request.

> DavException - throws a 400 (Bad Request) DavException if a request
> body is present but does not start with a DAV:lockinfo element. Note
> however, that a non-existing request body is a valid request used to
> refresh an existing lock.

What is a DAV:lockinfo element? Do I use the wrong url to access the repository?